# Books helping with most common mistakes of German learners?

Tags: grammar, learning

Is there anything one could recommend to get rid of the most common mistakes the non-native German speakers make?

I love the "[Is That What You Mean?](http://www.amazon.co.uk/That-What-You-Mean-Mistakes/dp/0582469015)" series by Pinguin which features very nice pictures illustrating every mistake:

[image: Is That What You Mean?]

It would be best to find something similar for German language. Images are not mandatory, but they are a very helpful visual aid for memorizing these mistakes and avoiding them.

Comment: What I learned just now: the correct form is "Try phoning Michael". (I took me some time to understand the cartoon.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: So nice of you to mention that. I did try and didn't get the point and was shy to ask!

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah, you're right. Not knowing whether there was some context missing I thought it had something to do with "trying to reach so."

Comment: @HendrikVogt As long as you figured it out on your own there are high chances that you'll never forget it ;-)

Comment: @Alexander: Indeed! That's also why I didn't provide more explanation - leave something to figure out `:-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something about idiomatic language, or mistakes in general? If the latter, I think you'd enjoy *[50 Ways to Improve Your German](http://www.amazon.ca/50-Ways-Improve-Your-German/dp/0071746331/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330217338&sr=8-1)*, it's very light and easy to read (alas, not many cartoons).

For something more comprehensive, *[1001 Pitfalls in German](http://www.amazon.ca/1001-Pitfalls-German-Henry-Strutz/dp/0812096525/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330217397&sr=1-1)* is pretty well-known.

Hope that helps!